# Is it possible to show keymatch result from GSA using regex?

Tags: google-search-appliance

Is it possible to show a keymatch result if there is a match using regex pattern?

For instance, I would like to show a result should a query begin with a certain pattern, for instance:

```
^cricket
```

I am hoping a keymatch result will then appear for queries like "cricket player", "cricket rules", "cricket stats" and so on.

If not regex, is there another method people are using?

Comment: I just got a tumbleweed badge for this. :(

Answer (score 1):

No, the built-in KeyMatch functionality doesn't allow this. The built-in functionality is very limited. I suggest you write your own off-GSA alternative, and have it inject values for you. This is actually pretty easy to do. You'd build a web application that stores the patterns and the corresponding URLs to serve. If you're using XSLT to render the results, build a OneBox service that the GSA can invoke. Otherwise, just render the results in your application server page.